# Angular route not triggered

Tags: angular, router

My site has routes similar to this:

```
https://example.com/boat/categories/name-3
```

I defined routes like this:

```js
    const routes: Routes = [
      {
        path: '',
        component: LayoutBoxComponent,
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            component: HomeComponent
          },
          {
            path: 'posts/:slug',
            component: PostComponent
          },
          {
            path: ':site_name',
            component: HomeComponent,
            children: [
              {
                path: 'categories/:by_category',
                component: CategoryComponent    <==== This component does not seems to triggered
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

When trying to access the route `https://example.com/boat/categories/name-3` the `CategoryComponent` is not called and I don't seems to know why. Ideas ?

## Edit

In my example:

```
https://example.com/boat/categories/name-3
```

is matching this pattern:

```
https://example.com/:site_name/categories/:by_category
```

`boat` here is dynamic. It could be `car` or `train` as well

Comment: where is the `boat` route ?

Comment: I dont know if this is allowed as parameterized route, maybe you can try path: '**' instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access child routes you need to use a `<router-outlet>` in the parent route.

So to access CategoryComponent you'd need both your LayoutBoxComponent and HomeComponent to have a `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` within their html file.

[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-b4kdcc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp-routing.module.ts) - can be tested by setting the route to: https://angular-ivy-b4kdcc.stackblitz.io/test/categories/x

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I don't really understand what you mean. Do you have an example ?

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked. I did in fact a refactor in my routes and forgot to add the `outlet` in my `HomeComponent` which is now a parent (was not before)

Comment: Happy to help. I've added an example anyway in case anyone stumbled upon it in the future :)